# How to not truncate Mongoid logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

This is how the Mongoid log the operations:

```
D, [2016-01-12T18:42:19.790639 #7906] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | localhost:27017 | app_test.update | STARTED | {"update"=>"users", "updates"=>[{"q"=>{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('5695652bc54d2d1ee200001e')}, "u"=>{"$addToSet"=>{"favorite_ids"=>{"$each"=>[BSON::ObjectId('5695652bc54d2d1ee200001f')]}}}, "multi"=>false, "upsert"=>false}], "writeConcern"=>{:w=>1}, "orde...
```

I want to be able to see the full log message. Is that possible?

Obs: I'm using **Mongoid 5**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After digging into [Mongo Ruby Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/blob/6e363f40fa7ab6c416f041c67508aa5b0c1d70a0/lib/mongo/monitoring/command_log_subscriber.rb#L31) (which is used by Mongoid >= 5), I've found a solution:

```
Mongo::Monitoring::CommandLogSubscriber::LOG_STRING_LIMIT = 1_000
```

**Edit**

The proper way to do this is add `truncate_logs` option to mongoid.yml file:

**config/mongoid.yml:**

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: database_name_development
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:
        truncate_logs: false
```

--

*Mongoid has a poor documentation*

Comment: This option in yml seems to be a null attempt :(

Comment: Which mongoid version are your using? Check out this: https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/03d69c97358ae3ede866b6cf776aecb4e57893c6/lib/rails/generators/mongoid/config/templates/mongoid.yml#L113

Comment: I tried to disable truncation via this setting but was unsuccessful. After debugging more I realized that the query was already truncated by the time it was passed to `Mongo::Monitoring::CommandLogSubscriber`. Any ideas how to untruncate further up the chain?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid truncates the logs so you should check your mongo logs. Here is how:

- First `ps aux | grep mongod`
- If you specified a log file you will find a `--logpath` option on your `mongod` instance.
- If not you will find something like this `mongod --profile=1 --slowms=1 --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`
- `cat /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` to find something like the following

  systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
    logAppend: true
- Then `tail -f /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

This way you can view full un-truncated logs.

If you can not see debug logs then login to `mongo`, choose your database and then `db.setLogLevel(number)` where `number` is between 1 to 5.

Read more about [`db.setLogLevel()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/)